# PHP scope issue in anonymous function

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

so I have these functions

```
function a(){
    int c = 1;
    b(function(){echo $c;});
}

function b($code){
    $code();
}
```

but somehow $c becomes undefined in the anonymous function
I know it's bacause that the anonymous function is it's own scope, but is there someway to make this work?

Comment: Is this PHP? Because you've tagged it as PHP, but your code isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you can use "use" statement.

```
function a()
{
    $c = 1;
    b(function() use ($c) {
        echo $c;
    });
}

function b($code){
    $code();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

When you put `$c` inside a function it's considered to be a `local scope` variable.